# What is difference between a formal system and a model of computation

Tags: computation-models

I don't exactly know the difference--partly because I cannot find a mathematical definition for a model of computation (also why is this)?

Comment: There are many mathematical models of computation depending on what you want to express https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_of_computation What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @ApoorvIngle I'd like to see a mathematical definition for "model of computation" not a particular example of a model of computation that is mathematically stated. The wiki you reference doesn't provide a precise definition for "model of computation"--it doesn't treat it as a maths object, it states it in English. Contrast this to clear maths definition of a formal language: subset of finite set of symbols together with Kleene star.

Comment: @ApoorvIngle https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/45856/what-is-a-model-of-computation-mathematically?noredirect=1#comment101929_45856   I asked this question separately